# Decision Network Expected Utility

Tags: probability, statistical-inference, conditional-probability, bayesian, bayesian-network

Suppose I am given the following decision network, with $t\in\{T_n,T_t,T_s\}$ being the decision:
[image]

$f\in\{F,\bar{F}\}$, $h\in\{H,\bar{H}\}$, $s\in\{S,\bar{S}\}$.

Suppose I am given $P(f)$, $P(s|f)$, $P(h|t,f)$, and $Utility(t,h)$. My goal is to find the expected utility of the optimal policy. I'm stuck because I'm not sure how to compute $P(h,s,f|t)$. How do I calculate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your network I deduce that $h$ is conditionally independent of $s$ given $f$ and $t$, i.e. 
$$P(h|f,s,t) = P(h|f,t), \tag{1}$$
and from the directionality of the arrows I guess that 
$$P(s,f|t) = P(s,f)\tag{2}.$$ Otherwise, I do not see how to answer the question. Assuming these two relations and the definition of conditional probability in the form
$$ P(a|b) = \frac{P(a,b)}{P(b)},$$
we have
\begin{align*}
P(f,h,s|t) &= \frac{P(f,h,s,t)}{P(t)} \\
&=\frac{P(h|f,s,t)P(f,s,t)}{P(t)}\\
(1)&= \frac{P(h|f,t)P(f,s,t)}{P(t)}\\
&=\frac{P(h|f,t)P(f,s|t)P(t)}{P(t)}\\
(2)&=P(h|f,t)P(f,s)\\
&=P(h|f,t)P(s|f)P(f),
\end{align*}
which are all known.

Comment: Perfect, you were right. Thank you so much!